# Topology not terminating automatically

Tags: apache-storm

We killed the topology by giving kill Topology method. We have the doubt that should we also give shutdown command in spite of kill topology command. We are running the topology once, it is working fine. 2nd time if we run the topology it is not running. Third time it is running. We are not able to resolve this. 2nd time the entire process is getting shutdown without showing the output. But 3rd time we are getting the output. Another problem is the process is not terminating automatically in the command prompt. Please do guide us.

Comment: did you use the storm UI for killing the topology? if yes then what was shown on the ui ? what do you mean by `entire process is getting shutdown` ? did you see any exception in the console ?

Comment: Are you using a cluster with zookeeper + storm cli? Or just running a local cluster? What is your configuration (JVM, storm version, OS)?

Comment: i have cleared the error.i have added the 5000 sec in Thread.sleep(5000) method.Thanks for your kind reply

Comment: I want to process xml file in storm using SAX parser.Can you please give the sample code for this process.I am using storm version9,Jdk 1.7.0. can you please guide us?